# É possível abrir uma extensão dll sem entrar no php.ini?

Tags: php

Eu preciso utilizar o `php_openssl.dll`, porém não tenho acesso ao `php.ini`, o servidor é estrangeiro e também o suporte está de difícil acesso.

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Tem alguma maneira de usa-lo sem entrar no `php.ini`?

Comment: Você sabe que pode aceitar respostas? Veja em [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Você pode aceitar uma resposta por pergunta que fez. Pode até aceitar a sua resposta se foi a que melhor ajudou você.

Answer (score 3):

**Linha de comando:**

O parametro `-d` é utilizado para definir valores no arquivo `.ini`:

`php -dextension=php_openssl.dll`

**Tempo de execução:**

> Esta função foi removida a partir da versão 5.3

Para carregar a extensão em tempo de execução, use a função [dl](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.dl.php):

```
<?php

if (!extension_loaded('openssl')) {
    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
        dl('php_openssl.dll');
    } else {
        dl('openssl.so');
    }
}
```

Comment: É possível colocar em um arquivo .php? <?php php -dextension=php_openssl.dll ?>

Comment: Editei a resposta. @FelipeJorge

Comment: @lúcio-rubens, segundo o site do PHP a função `dl()` foi removida no PHP 5.3 (vide: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php) =/

Comment: Adicionei a informação. Obrigado pela sinalização! @MateusDemboski

Comment: Esta informação é muito útil porém a versão do meu PHP é 5.3.29.

Answer (score 3):

Presumindo que você esteja usando apache e que você tem permição para isso, é possivle por meio de um arquivo .htaccess com o seguinte conteudo:

```
#verifica se o módulo do PHP 5 para o apache foi carregado
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
#define o caminho para sua pasta de extensões
php_xtension_dir /caminh/absoluto/para/sua/pasta/de/extencoes/
#carrega os modulos
php_extension mbstring.so
php_extension openssl.so
php_extension libcurl.so
</IfModule>
```

Comment: E como eu colocaria isto dentro do arquivo php?

Comment: Olá @felipe-jorge! Este código não vai dentro de um arquivo PHP e sim, como esta na resposta, em um arquivo `.htaccess`, que deve ser criado preferencialmente na raiz do projeto.

Comment: Este arquivo pode ter qualquer nome. Por exemplo dll.htaccess?

Comment: Não, ele precisa ser de nome .htaccess

Comment: mas ele não tem extensão?

Comment: Pois então, esse nome vem do linux, onde o "." indica que é um arquivo oculto, portanto ele não possui extensão e, ao menos que você mude nas configurações do apache, o arquivo precisa ter o nome de ".htaccess"...